Getting data in JPA from table with foreign keys and additional data
I have 3 tables in database (Postgres). The first (A) has its parameters as well as the third (C). There is the second one (B) which contains only foreign keys to A and C. But other than that it contains (recently added) one other information “name”.
For A and C I have JPA entities.
I used to use this code to access information from C in A. I need now to access the “name” from B table as well. Is there some simple workaround or do I have to create new JPA entity for table B?
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name = “TABLE_B”,
  joinColumns = {
  @JoinColumn(name = “TABLE_A_ID”)
  }
  , inverseJoinColumns = {
  @JoinColumn(name = “TABLE_C_ID”)
}
)
private Collection<TableC> myData;



I'm afraid you need to create an entity for table B. How would you otherwise be able to get the name? Where should it be stored if you only have an entity relationship A<->C from a JPA point of view?

@Thomas how would u suggest the B entity should look like? In my database the B entity does not have id. How would u define foreign keys? At the end how would I accessed the data? Sorry I am new to this.

There are several tutorials on how to set this up but it would basically have a composite key which consists of the foreign keys to tables A and C as well as the name attribute. Additionally, the many-to-many relationship between A and C would be replaced with one-to-many A->B and C->B as well as the inverse many-to-one.
